# Convert 4 corners into a matrix for OpenGL to Direct3D sprite conversion

Tags: math, opengl, matrix, directx, transform

I am working on code for Scrolling Game Development Kit.  An old release (2.0) of this program was based on DirectX and was using Direct3D Sprite objects to draw all the graphics.  It used the Transform property of the sprite object to specify how the texture rectangle would be transformed as it was being output to the display.  The current release (2.1) was a conversion to OpenGL and is using GL TexCoord2 and GL Vertex2 calls to send coordinates of the source and output rectangles for drawing sprites.  Now someone says that their video card worked great with DirectX, but their OpenGL drivers do not support GL_ARB necessary to use NPOTS textures (pretty basic).  So I'm trying to go back to DirectX without reverting everything back to 2.0.  Unfortunately it seems it's much easier to get 4 points given a matrix than it is to get a matrix given 4 points.  I have done away with all the matrix info in version 2.1 so I only have the 4 corner points left when calling the function that draws images on the display.  Is there any way to use the 4 corner information to transform a Direct3D Sprite?

Alternatively does anybody know why DirectX would be able to do something than OpenGL can't -- are some video cards' drivers just that bad where DirectX supports NPOTS textures but OpenGL doesn't?

Comment: How old is that system, that is doesn't support NPOT textures? These have been around for 10 years. You can also use normal textures and pad the unused space.

Comment: I think the system is pretty old, and the drivers for OpenGL may never have been developed very well; I don't know -- I haven't seen it.  In any case, my other problem with trying to switch to POT textures is that all my coordinates are based on pixels rather than 0-1 values, which is another feature of GL_ARB textures.  Would it be easier to try and make this work with OpenGL somehow than to try to switch back to DirectX?

Comment: Converting the range 0..1 to pixels is easy enough.

Comment: According to the person reporting the problem, the problem is seen on multiple systems: X60 Lenovo Thinkpad, Windows 7, used utility "OpenGL Extensions Viewer 3.0" Says all the drivers are up to date and passes all GL tests up to OpenGL 1.4.  Other is Compaq Prescario something, but not many details on that one.
It had a VIA/S3G Unichrome IGP Display driver Up to date, and supported OpenGL.

Comment: If I start using floats instead of pixel coordinates to specify texture coordinates, is there a risk that I'll get some rounding error and pick up partial neighboring pixels while copying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably worth reading up on how they do bump mapping. See e.g. [this site](http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html). You end up with a tangent space matrix, which maps from world space to tangent space (the space relative to the current face). The purpose of that is taking a vector in world space, generally a vector from a light, and converting it into a vector in tangent space, that being the space that your texture defines surface normals in.

Anyway, if you inverted that matrix you'd have a mapping from tangent space to world space. Which I think is what you want? The mapping produced in that tutorial is purely for direction vectors, but expanding out to a 4x4 and anchoring the origin somewhere meaningful shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I'm only dealing in 2D here so it's probably simpler than whatever gives me a 4x4 matrix.  I don't even remember doing matrices in school even though I went through advanced algebra and calculus and got a BS in computer science... maybe that's more of a memory problem than a school problem though :).  I do remember at least learning what they were for (transformation), but not doing enough with them to remember how they really work.

Comment: Can the transformation applied always be described e.g. as a rotation and a scale? It's very easy to recover a matrix for that if you've four transformed points from a rectangular original.

Comment: It can often be a flip as well, and could conceivably be any 2-D transformation matrix because I allowed the user to type in the matrix parameters directly.

Comment: I ended up sticking with OpenGL and eliminating my reliance on GL_ARB_texture_rectangle instead.  That was much easier than I expected, and made everything work without switching back to DirectX.  But since that doesn't really answer the question, I'll accept the only reply to the question that we do have.